# MongoDB: how to calculate between item[n] and item[n+1] using aggregate?

Tags: mongodb

How do I count the number of days between two dates in MongoDB using aggregation? I have an array of sorted items with dates like below.

```
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-10-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-09-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
    }
```

I want to count the days (or amount of time) between each date. So `item[0].date - item[1].date`, `item[1].date - item[2].date` and so on. Last item would not have a date.

The results should look like this:

```
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-10-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "num_days": 29
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-09-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "num_days": 32
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "num_days": null
    }
```

I want to accomplish this using `aggregate()`. Is this possible? What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this aggregation pipeline

Logic is `$push` the dates to an array, iterate array by index using `$range`, `$map` date using `$arrayElemAt`, calculate days by `$subtract`ing `$arrayElemAt` index and index+1 and divide it by `86400000` to get the days from milliseconds

millisecond to day

```
86400000 = 24*60*60*1000
```

pipeline

```
db.dt.aggregate([
    {$group : {_id : null, dates : {$push : "$date"}}}, 
    {$project : {dates : {
        $map : {
            input : {$range : [0, {$size :"$dates"}]}, 
            as : "idx", 
            in : {
                date : {$arrayElemAt : ["$dates", "$$idx"]}, 
                days : {$divide: [{$subtract : [{$arrayElemAt : ["$dates", "$$idx"]}, {$arrayElemAt : ["$dates", {$sum : ["$$idx", 1]}]}]}, 86400000]}}}
    }}},
    {$unwind : "$dates"},
    {$replaceRoot : {newRoot : "$dates"}}
]).pretty()
```

output

```
{ "date" : ISODate("2018-10-07T00:00:00Z"), "days" : 29 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2018-09-08T00:00:00Z"), "days" : 32 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2018-08-07T00:00:00Z"), "days" : null }
```

**EDIT**

its safer to do `$sort` and `$match` before to filter the documents not required